# Swift type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View' with protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui

There probably has been a question similar to this, but it seems most of them are "not quite" the same as what I'm asking. I'm coming from an Objective-C background, where it's trivial to declare objects as conforming to protocols and directly passing messages to protocol-conforming types. The Swift type system to me seems extremely overly complicated, but alas I'm trying to learn.

I'm building a generic "tabbed view" where a number of tabs is displayed at the top of the screen, and each tab has it's own "content view" which is displayed below when the tab is "active." The problem I'm running into is something to do with protocol types. I have the following protocol:

```
protocol TabItem : Identifiable
{
    associatedtype ContentView: View

    var title: String { get }

    var id: UUID { get }

    var contentView: ContentView { get }
}
```

And the a view which can display the tab itself (previously, this was a generic view with `<T : TabItem>` for the `item` property, but I ran into more protocol issues here:

```
struct TabView : View
{
    var item: any TabItem

    var body : some View {
        /* Tab view implementation here */
    }
}
```

Finally, I have the view which displays the tabs and their content, and the following is very intuitive to me, but it gives me a cryptic error message of `Type 'any View' cannot conform to View`:

```
struct TabbedView : View
{
    var items: [any TabItem]
    var activeItem: (any TabItem)?

    var body : some View {
        ForEach(self.items, id: \.id) { item in
            TabView(item: item)
        }

        Divider()

        if let activeItem = self.activeItem {
            // The error appears here
            activeItem.contentView
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this while keeping it generic? I want to be able to put any view in `ContentView` for various classes which implement the `TabItem` protocol. I understand the compiler likely wants to be able to strictly type check things or something like this, but it seems like there's been a huge functionality sacrifice to achieve this? Is there some specific pattern I should be using that I don't know about?

Comment: As a side note, the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74892613/swiftui-protocol-with-view-property-returns-error-type-any-view-cannot-confor?rq=2 here doesn't work since the compiler will then not be able to instantiate `TabView` in the `ForEach` since it cannot determine the underlying type for the generic `TabView<T>` instance.

Comment: You will probably have to wrap your views into AnyView, although that will break animations. The main problem is that you try to create a view whose type (the actual View implementation of your protocol) is not known at compile time. That is why you have to use (any TabItem) in the first place. SwiftUI, however, relies on static type information to do its magic. Maybe try to change your question. What is it you actually want to do? It can probably be done correctly from somewhere higher up your View hierarchy.

Comment: Could `some` work here, `var activeItem: (some TabItem)?`? And drop `self.` inside the `if`, you want to use the unwrapped value

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The compiler segfaults on this so I guess not haha. Yes sorry I mistyped the `self.`

Comment: You can even write `if let activeItem { ...`

Comment: What you are looking for are [Parameter Packs](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10168).

Answer (score 2):

While the simple solution is to just wrap the `ContentView` in an `AnyView`...

```
// in TabItem
var contentAsAnyView: AnyView { AnyView(contentView) }
// use the above in the body of TabbedView
```

[It is better to avoid `AnyView`](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc21/10022/).

Let's see how the existing SwiftUI [`TabView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview) works. You are supposed to put all the tabs' contents into a view builder

```
TabView {
    ReceivedView()
        .badge(2)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Received", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")
        }
    SentView()
        .tabItem {
            Label("Sent", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.up.fill")
        }
    AccountView()
        .badge("!")
        .tabItem {
            Label("Account", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.fill")
        }
}
```

The key thing here is that by using a view builder, `TabView` avoids needing all the types of the tabs as its type parameter. Whatever view the view builder builds, will be the type of `TabView`'s `Content` type parameter.

We can do something similar, except we don't know how many tabs there are (See [here](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc21/10022/) for an idea of how SwiftUI can do this), so we will need users to pass an array of "tab identifiers", and we will then ask the user to give us a tab `View` for each of them.

```
struct TabbedView<Selection: Hashable, Body: View>: View {
    
    let tabs: [Selection]
    @State var selection: Selection
    
    let computeView: (Selection) -> Body
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // simple view for picking tabs
            Picker("Tabs", selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                    // replace this with your custom tab item view
                    Text(String(describing: tab))
                    // also consider removing the Selection type parameter 
                    // and using a concrete type from which you can make
                    // a tab item view
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)

            computeView(selection)
        }
    }
    
    init(tabs: [Selection], @ViewBuilder computeView: @escaping (Selection) -> Body) {
        self.tabs = tabs
        self._selection = State(initialValue: tabs.first!)
        self.computeView = computeView
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
enum Tabs: Int, CaseIterable {
    case tab1, tab2, tab3
}

TabbedView(tabs: Tabs.allCases) { selection in
    switch selection {
    case .tab1:
        Text("Tab 1")
    case .tab2:
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
    case .tab3:
        Button("Button") { }
    }
}
```